# Задание с собеседования - объяснить почему не работает код

Tags: c#

Знакомому на собеседовании дали задание, объяснить почему не работает код, в общем, собеседование он так и не прошел, а над тестовым заданием мы решили вместе посидеть, своими силами ни к какому толковому результату не пришли, может вы сможете подсказать что тут не так. Код компилируется, но ниразу не выполняется.

```
class MiddleTask
{
    delegate bool Comparer(int a, int b);
    delegate void Executer(string message);
    static int MaxValue(int a, int b, Comparer comp)
    {
        return comp(a, b) ? a : b;
    }
    static void TExecute(int cicle, Executer method)
    {
        var inc = 0;
        while (inc <--cicle)
        {    
            method("Execute method-comparer");
        }
    }        

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Entry point...");
        TExecute(3, (dy) =>
        {
            var targetRangeModel = new
            {
                range = 0,
                comparerPrefix = "Compare result:"
            };

            var index = 0;
            var target = 20;

            while (index-- > targetRangeModel.range && target-- > index)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(targetRangeModel.comparerPrefix + ">>>" +
                    MaxValue(22, 15,
                    (x, y) =>
                        {
                            return (x > y) ? true : false;
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Что такое "не работает код" ? Не компилируется, не запускается, возвращает ошибку, возвращает неверный результат (а какой тогда верный)? *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас ни разу не выполняется цикл

```
while (index-- > targetRangeModel.range && target-- > index)
```

Т.к. условие `index-- > targetRangeModel.range` всегда будет ложно

Comment: Вот же) Попался на --> && <-- думаю, что за операторы магические.